# LLVM: "invalid redefinition of function" that has not previously been defined

Tags: llvm, forward-declaration, llvm-ir, function-declaration, function-definition

I'm working on a compiler to produce LLVM IR code for a toy language (for a class).

However, I keep getting a strange error: "invalid redefinition of function Main_main". This function is only defined once, as grepping for "Main_main" shows:

```
$ grep "Main_main" test.ll
declare %Object* @Main_main(%Main*)
    %Object* (%Main*) * @Main_main
    %vtpm.1 = call %Object*(%Main* ) @Main_main( %Main* %vtpm.0 )
define %Object* @Main_main(%Main* %_self_var) {
```

The first line is where it's declared, the second is where a pointer to it is stored in a vtable, the third is where it's called, and the fourth is where it's defined. Surely only one of those counts as a definition?

The exact error message:

```
$ llvm-as test.ll -o test.bc
llvm-as: test.ll:179:17: error: invalid redefinition of function 'Main_main'
define %Object* @Main_main(%Main* %_self_var) {
                ^
```

What am I doing wrong, that makes LLVM think this is a **re**definition?

Comment: Please share the entire test.ll, or at least the functions where `Main_main` is called and defined.

Answer (score 0):

The IR you show is syntactically incorrect. Functions declared with `declare` could not have bodies and even if they could, you are missing curly braces. You should have something like

```
declare %Object* @Main_main(%Main*)

define %Object* @Main_main(%Main* %_self_var) {
...
}
```

Also, it seems you are generating textual IR by hand. The canonical way to do that is via C++/C/whatever API. This would ensure code correctness by means of type safety or additional checks.

Comment: Agreed on not generating textual IR directly; unfortunately for this class that's what we need to do. (Part of the assignment is doing all the bookkeeping by hand.) But right now, my `declare` doesn't have a body—the bit I've shown is the output of grep, finding all the places where `Main_main` appears in the program.